# Get BuddyPress email tokens in usable form for PHP

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

With BuddyPress email templates, we're using tokens from the Codex like `{{recipient.email}}` and `{{recipient.name}}` and `{{recipient.username}}` --- however, these can only be used within the HTML portion of the template. Is there a way to get this data as a PHP variable?

ie. something like `$recipientname={{recipient.name}};`

Answer (score 0):

I found a roundabout way to do this but there has to be a better way?

```
ob_start(); 
?>{{recipient.email}}<?php 
$user_email=ob_get_clean();
```